# Is it okay to use constructors to initialize a 2D Vector as a one-liner in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, constructor, 2d

Is it okay to initialize a 2D vector like this (here all values in a 5x4 2D vectro are initialized to 3)?

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > foo(5, std::vector<int>(4, 3));
```

This seems to behave okay, but everywhere I look on the web people seem to recommend initializing such a vector with for loops and push_back(). I was initially afraid that all rows here would point to the same vector, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is perfectly valid - You'll get a 2D vector ([5, 4] elements) with every element initialized to 3.

For most other cases (where you e.g. want different values in different elements) you cannot use any one-liner - and therefore need loops.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the code is valid and it indeed does what you want it to do (assuming I understood your intent correctly).

However, doing it that way is generally inefficient (at least in the current version of the language/library). The above initialization creates a temporary vector and then initializes individual sub-vectors by *copying* the original. That can be rather inefficient. For this reason in many cases it is preferrable to construct the top-level vector by itself

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > foo(5);
```

and then iterate over it and build its individual sub-vectors in-place by doing something like

```
foo[i].resize(4, 3);
```

Comment: The cost of the one-liner approach is construction of a single inner temporary vector - so not **very** inefficient IMO.

Comment: @Erik: Construction *and* destruction. But not only that. The cost also includes the cost of initialization by vector-to-vector copying, as opposed to the cost of element-to-vector copying in case in-place construction. For primitive types, the difference is actually qualitative.

Comment: As I see it, the copy-ctor variant will end up to a series of memcpy-equivalent calls, whereas the loops will evaluate to a series of memset-equivalent calls. At least if the compiler is somewhat optimizing. Yes, memcpy could be considered more expensive than memset - but with the source data presumably in cache and the target data presumably not, I don't think you'll see practical differences for this scenario. If the vectors were larger or contained complex objects, sure, for his ints - prefer readability. Your point is quite valid though, the copy ctor *can* be more inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful commentary. In general, I rarely want/need to do this sort of vector initialization in a time-critical chunk of code, but I will keep this in mind.